# CSS grid with biggest squares without overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a layout where I have a toolbar on top and, below it, a board for *squared* cards taking all the space left

I managed to do most of it, as shown in the code below. The only missing requirement where I'm stuck is that the squares need to be the biggest possible **without causing an overflow** of the board in either direction. In my example, I control the size of the cards with

```
.card {
    width: 51px;
    height: 51px;
...
}
```

but i don't know how to calculate that number dynamically. It doesn't necessarily need to be reactive, i.e. once set, if you resize the board or rotate the screen, the grid doesn't need to re-adjust, so javascript solutions to calculate the initial card size are ok too if it's easier than pure css.

The number of rows and columns in the grid is calculated in javascript based on the number of cards to render (12 in my example) and the orientation of the screen (e.g. to decide if 4X3 or 3X4) and set in the `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` but this is not shown in my example

```css
#board {
  margin: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: red;
}

.card {
  width: 51px; /*how to control these without hardcoding them*/
  height: 51px; /*how to control these without hardcoding them*/
  justify-self: center;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <image id="back" />
    <image id="restart" />
  </div>
  <div id="board">
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I also tried making the size of the cards' width and height be 100% and instead playing with the width and height of the board itself but I couldn't find a solution either

Comment: do you want like this? - https://ibb.co/3kMXkqM

Comment: @s.kuznetsov in that one the yellow div is not squared. my goal is the biggest square that doesn't overflow

Comment: do you just want to avoid parent overflow by making the squares as large as possible? Should the squares stretch horizontally to fill the empty space?

Comment: let me rephrase it from a user's perspective. I want to see the biggest squares possible without having to scroll right or down. The spacing between them should be minimum `grid-x-gap`. Because a screen is usually not squared, there will be one dimension where the spacing between cards will be the minimum and the other where it will be bigger

Comment: here is an example with 2 different boards. they both have the same width but the first one is much shorter than the second one. I did it by tweaking the card size by hand. the question is how to do it automatically
https://imgur.com/a/RP1gxQI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewport unit combined with `min()` can help you:

```css
#board {
  --s: min(
      (100vw - 5*10px)/4,  /* the width of square (5 gaps and 4 square in a column) */
      (100vh - 50px - 4*10px)/3 /* the height of square (4 gaps, height of toolbar and 3 square in a row) */
      ); /* we take the smallest value and use for both width/height */
  
  display: grid;
  margin:10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: red;
  height:50px;
}

.card {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--s);
  justify-self: center;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<div id="board">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Also like below:

```css
#board {
  --s: min(
      (100vw - 5*10px)/4,  /* the width of square (5 gaps and 4 square in a column) */
      (100vh - 50px - 4*10px)/3 /* the height of square (4 gaps, height of toolbar and 3 square in a row) */
      ); /* we take the smallest value and use for both width/height */
  
  display: grid;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: red;
  height:50px;
}

.card {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--s);
  margin: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<div id="board">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may not be as your approach (using grid) but it may help.
It is responsive and will change as screen dimension does change.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #board {
        margin: 30px;
        height: calc( 100% - 100px );
    }

    #toolbar {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .card {
        float:left;
        width: calc( 25% - 20px );
        height: 33%;
        margin: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```